# Calculate the derivative ([i] - [i - 1]) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, derivative

Trivial using a for loop or each_with_index, just wondering if there was a better way of doing it using Ruby syntax.

I need to create a new array that is the derivative of the source array, eg:

```
for(int i = 1; i < oldArray.length; i++)
{
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i] - oldArray[i-1]
}
```

Comment: Hey, no fair picking a winner before I could even type mine up :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
old_array.each_cons(2).map{|x, y| y - x}
```

`Enumerable#each_cons` called with with a chunk size of 2 but without a block returns an Enumerator which will iterate over each pair of consecutive elements in `old_array`.  Then we just use `map` to perform a subtraction on each pair.

Comment: I just ran it on [1,2,3,4] and I get [1,1,1].

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of each_slice?  That would give [1,1].

Comment: the code as it is written requires 1.8.7 i believe. however, you can write it as "old_array.enum_cons(2).map{|x, y| y - x}" and it will work on previous versions too

Answer (score 1):

```
last=0
new = old.map{|v|x=v-last;last=v;x}[1..-1]
```